Custom labels with enumitem and hyperref
I'm creating enumerate lists with the enumitem package.
Sometimes, I want a single item with a custom label. The basic functionality is provided by \item[customlablename], but it has shortcomings. A subsequent \label won't produce the right label text. Moreover, hyperref does not work as expected.
The closest thing I have is (based on this answer):
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\makeatletter\newcommand\customitem[1]{\item[#1]\def\@currentlabel{#1}}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
\item\label{a} \lipsum
\item\label{b} \lipsum
\customitem{(ii')}\label{bb} \lipsum
\item\label{c} \lipsum
\end{enumerate}
References: \ref{a}, \ref{b}, \ref{bb}, \ref{c}.
\end{document}

The problem is that clicking on the reference (ii') in the pdf viewer leads to (ii) (and not to (ii')).
Is there a way to solve this?

The link does not have anything to latch on to. Add \phantomsection to that def

maybe \MakeLinkTarget rather than \phantomsection @daleif?

@cfr aren't they more or less the same thing?

Advantage of course is that your is in modern kernels even without hyperref

@daleif ulrike told me to use \MakeLinkTarget when it wasn't a section. at least, I thought that was what she meant.

@cfr probably best to follow her advise. Though having to add an extra counter is annoying

@daleif it is very possible I misunderstood.

off-topic a bit: you should load hyperref after enumitem, though I don't think it makes a difference in this case.

@cfr ok, I will load hyperref after enumifem. Just out of interest: why?

@azimut because when several different packages want to redefine the same internal commands, it generally matters which order they do it in. this is less true than it used to be, but the advice is still to load hyperref late i.e. last unless there's something you know specifically needs to come later. e.g. if you use cleveref, you need to load that after hyperref. but in most cases, you want to load things before hyperref, especially if they involve references or cross-references or anything involving \label.

@cfr thank you for the explanation. Makes sense of course.

Updated thanks to Ulrike Fischer's comment.
Probably?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/731906/
% addaswyn yn ôl sylwad Ulrike Fischer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/731900/custom-labels-with-enumitem-and-hyperref/731906?noredirect=1#comment1822947_731906
\makeatletter\newcommand\customitem[1]{\item[#1{\MakeLinkTarget[item]{}}]\def\@currentlabel{#1}}\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[(i)]
  \item\label{a} \lipsum
  \item\label{b} \lipsum
  \customitem{(ii')}\label{bb} \lipsum
  \item\label{c} \lipsum
\end{enumerate}
References: \ref{a}, \ref{b}, \ref{bb}, \ref{c}.
\end{document}


do I need the \def\@currentlabel if I've got \refstepcounter?

This works for me. Thank you!!

It doesn't make much sense to use \refstepcounter and MakeLinkTarget. That creates two anchor. Simply \MakeLinkTarget[item]{} is enough. And I would put the target inside the item argument.

@UlrikeFischer many thanks! I simplified the line to \makeatletter\newcommand\customitem[1]{\item[#1]\MakeLinkTarget[item]{}\def\@currentlabel{#1}}\makeatother and it works.

@UlrikeFischer hopefully edited correctly.

@azimut yes, but that doesn't put the target into the argument of \item. see edit above.

@cfr ok thank you then I will use your updated version. What is the advantage of having the target in the argument of item?

@cfr thinking again, the reason might be that the anchor is placed exactly on the item and not behind, right?

@azimut you need to ask ulrike. she writes the code, so if she says it's better in the argument, that's highly likely to be true. but I have no idea why that is better than, say, right after it. if the item is larger and gets moved to the next page, you'd end up with the target going with the content rather than staying with the label? but I don't know if that's why. I don't even know for sure I understood the comment correctly in the first place ....

@UlrikeFischer ^^^

@cfr put an X beside the target and in the item and then consider which x you want to hit with a link.
